# How to disable ComponentWill... warnings when they are coming from dependencies

Tags: react-native

**Issue**

I am getting constant yellow warnings from React Native about component lifecycle, such as ComponentWillMount being deprecated
These warnings come from dependencies, and not from my components.

**What I do not need**

I can't fix this by disabling the yellow box altogether, nor can I modify React Native's code directly, meaning a solution like this in RN's `renderApplication.js` isn't valid:

```js
const backup = console.warn;

console.warn = function filterWarnings(warning) {
  const supressedWarnings = [
    'Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
  ];

  if (
    warning.length &&
    !supressedWarnings.some((entry) => warning.includes(entry))
  ) {
    backup.apply(console, arguments);
  }
};
```

I also cannot modify the code from the dependencies.

**Question**

Can I disable these warnings from a place such as the application's root file, and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are doing with `filterWarnigns` but you can disable warning through the [`LoxBox`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox).

E.g.:

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

// Ignore log notification by message:
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
    'Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
]);
```

## For `react-native` versions below 0.63 use [`YellowBox`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.62/debugging#warnings):

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
    'Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.',
]);
```

Comment: The better solution here would probably be to update your library though

Comment: This worked great, thanks a lot! I am working in a huge project with an insane amount of dependencies and some of them have legacy code even in their latest version, so I cannot go that way.